# angular2 rxjs groupby with count

Tags: angular, rxjs, rxjs5

use angular4 with rxjs 5.4.0

I am trying to group list by 'type' and get their count. can some one help ? following is my code

```
export class Sample{
  type:string;
  data:any ...
  ...
}
```

I have array of Sample Class

```
list:Sample[] = // number of elements

Observable.from(this.list).groupBy(x=> x.type)
  .flatMap( group => {
    return group.reduce; // how can i use reduce function to count numbers and return map of type and their count
  }
})
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're close, I think you just need a few more operators on the grouped observable.

```
const list = [{ type: 'foo' }, { type: 'bar' }, { type: 'bar' }];

Observable.from( list ).groupBy( x => x.type )
  .mergeMap( list$ => { // each emission is a stream

    /* A stream of "aggregated" data. */
    const count$ = list$.count();

    /* Format the result. */
    return count$.map( count => ({ type: list$.key, count }));
  });
```

This emits:

```
{ type: 'foo', total: 1 }
{ type: 'bar', total: 2 }
```

It sounds like you might have more complicated use cases for calculating "aggregates", maybe you need to sum `Sample.data`. If so, you just need to change my `count$` implementation with your own. Let's say `data` is a list of numbers:

```
const list = [{
  type: 'foo',
  data: [1,2,3]
}, {
  type: 'bar',
  data: [4,5,6]
}, {
  type: 'bar',
  data: [7,8,9]
}];

Observable.from( list ).groupBy( x => x.type )
  .mergeMap( list$ => { // each emission is a stream

    /* A stream of "aggregated" data. */
    const count$ = list$.reduce( ( accumulator, sample ) => { // reduce the stream
      return accumulator + sample.data.reduce( ( acc, datum ) => { // reduce the array
        return acc + datum;
      }, 0);
    }, 0);

    /* Format the result. */
    return count$.map( count => ({ type: list$.key, count }));
  });
```

This produces:

```
{ type: 'foo', total: 6 }
{ type: 'bar', total: 39 }
```

Comment: You could simplify this, as the value with which the grouping is made is available via the `key` property on the [`GroupedObservable`](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/operator/groupBy.js~GroupedObservable.html). That is, you don't need to use `list$.take( 1 ).map( x => x.type )` to obtain it; just use `list$.key`.